# How to assert a selected item in a dojo multiselect with selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, combobox, dojo

I've populated a multiselect using dojo and added the selected values using combo.set("value", selectedValuesArray);

Problem is that when trying to assert the selected values using selenium IDE, I can't figure out how dojo does to "select" the selected values, I would expect to be like

```
<option value="111" selected>name</option>
```

But as you can see in the image, there's no indication in the image, not in the disabled (view) or the enabled (edit) one

There's no CSS classes added either, so i don't know how to assert if the item is selected or not.

Any idea?

Here's the generated HTML

```
<select data-dojo-attach-event="onchange: _onChange" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,focusNode" name="combo_project_participants" multiple="true" class="dijitMultiSelect" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_MultiSelect_3" widgetid="dijit_form_MultiSelect_3">
       <option value="1367">name 0 AdminEdge</option>
       <option value="1368">Test User name Test User lname</option>
</select>
```

EDIT:  this didn't allowed me to upload the image...

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/cf6a.jpg

Comment: The items got selected, and they're correctly showing, but there's no CSS or parameter that indicates it, so i cannot assert with Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
data-dojo-type="dijit/form/MultiSelect"
```

in your select-Tag. That should fix it.

For further information look at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/MultiSelect.html

Regards

Comment: Sadly it didn't, it still shows the selected items, but there is no indication in the code on how is selected.